# Logic to modify multiple nodes of xml variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, ssms

I am stuck working with an xml datatype in sql server.

I am trying to replace multiple nodes of an xml variable in sql server, using modify(replace value of .. with ..) but haven't been successful.

Could you please share your thoughts on how I could best handle the query?

Thank you...

Issue:

In the XML(variable), I am trying to set text in Value element to "White" for all attributes with CustomProperty Name="Color"

The Value element is like Black

But, Value can contain any other color, even "#rrggbb" RGB codes are allowed.

The xml:

```
DECLARE @xmled XML
SET @xmled =   
     <SemanticModel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/10/semanticmodeling" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="Gd54bb96e-8704">
      <Culture>en-US</Culture>
     <Entities>
     <Entity ID="G6356ce91-8a88">
      <CustomProperties>
        <CustomProperty Name="UpdateRowKey">
          <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Gee0eb52b-44ad</Value>
        </CustomProperty>
      </CustomProperties>
      <Name>Entity 1</Name>
      <CollectionName>Entity 1</CollectionName>
      <IdentifyingAttributes>
        <AttributeReference>
          <AttributeID>Gee0eb52b-308d-44ad-96e4-75b1cfa1d36e</AttributeID>
        </AttributeReference>
      </IdentifyingAttributes>
      <InstanceSelection>MandatoryFilter</InstanceSelection>
      <Fields>
        <Attribute ID="Gee0eb52b-308d">
          <CustomProperties>
            <CustomProperty Name="Color">
              <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Red</Value>
            </CustomProperty>
          </CustomProperties>
          <Name>Attribute 1</Name>
          <DataType>String</DataType>
          <SortDirection>Ascending</SortDirection>
          <Width>4</Width>
          <DataCulture>en-US</DataCulture>
          <DiscourageGrouping>true</DiscourageGrouping>
          <EnableDrillthrough>true</EnableDrillthrough>
          <ContextualName>Merge</ContextualName>
          <Column Name="Attribute 1" />
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute ID="Gd93eaa72-a953">
          <CustomProperties>
            <CustomProperty Name="Color">
              <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">White</Value>
            </CustomProperty>
          </CustomProperties>
          <Name>Attribute 2</Name>
          <DataType>String</DataType>
          <Nullable>true</Nullable>
          <SortDirection>Ascending</SortDirection>
          <Width>2</Width>
          <DataCulture>en-US</DataCulture>
          <ValueSelection>Dropdown</ValueSelection>
          <Column Name="Attribute 2" />
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute ID="G834638ef-f136">
          <CustomProperties>
            <CustomProperty Name="Color">
              <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Blue</Value>
            </CustomProperty>
          </CustomProperties>
          <Name>Attribute 3</Name>
          <DataType>String</DataType>
          <Nullable>true</Nullable>
          <SortDirection>Ascending</SortDirection>
          <Width>7</Width>
          <DataCulture>en-US</DataCulture>
          <ValueSelection>Dropdown</ValueSelection>
          <Column Name="Attribute 3" />
        </Attribute>
       </Fields>
        <Table Name="table1" />
       </Entity>
      </Entities>
    </SemanticModel>
```